# I need to sort Character array based on another integer array. Below is my code

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

my integer array is like this **[3,1,2,5,4]** and my character array is like this **[a, b, c, d, e]** . If i sort the integer array it becomes **[1,2,3,4,5]** . Now, I want my characters in the character array change their positions according to the numbers in the integer array ,so the resultant char array should be like this **[b, c, a, e, d]** . I hope u got the question.

```java
public class Comparator1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] ele = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
        int[] freq = { 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 };
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ele));
//op: char[] ele={b,c,a,e,d};
    }

}
```

Comment: You definitely need to be more specific. Are you wanting to sort the char array based on the int array's corresponding ordered integer when converted from char? For example, [ 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e' ] and [ 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 ] becomes [ 'c', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'd' ]? Or should the integers in the int array represent indexes for the char array? For example, the last example would now have an output of [ 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'c' ]. The question needs more context.

Comment: my integer array is like this [3,1,2,5,4] and my character array is like this [a, b, c, d, e] . If i sort the integer array it becomes [1,2,3,4,5] . Now, i want my characters in the character array change their positions according to the numbers in the integer array ,so the resultant char array should be like this **[b, c, a, e, d]** . Understood???

Comment: If that's the case, check "Case 2" of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not have duplications in `freq` array, you can use `TreeMap`:

```java
public static char[] sort(char[] ele, int[] freq) {
    Map<Integer, Character> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
        map.put(freq[i], ele[i]);

    int i = 0;

    for (Character ch : map.values())
        ele[i++] = ch;

    return ele;
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can use `PriorityQueue`:

```java
public static char[] sort(char[] ele, int[] freq) {
    class Pair {

        final char ele;
        final int freq;

        public Pair(char ele, int freq) {
            this.ele = ele;
            this.freq = freq;
        }

    }

    Queue<Pair> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(pair -> pair.freq));

    for (int i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
        queue.add(new Pair(ele[i], freq[i]));

    int i = 0;

    for (Pair pair : queue)
        ele[i++] = pair.ele;

    return ele;
}
```

Comment: In Java 16+, that `Pair` class definition can be reduced to a brief record: `record Pair ( char ele , int freq ) {}`. And it can be declared locally within a method (as can enums and interfaces now).

Comment: I use `Java11`, but in any case the most important is an **idea**. Implemention could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Converting it into map can help u in better way as you can sort map easily. Try below code

```
    char ele[] = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    int freq[] = new int[] { 5, 4, 7, 2, 1 };
    int n=ele.length;
    //this will check whether both have same element or not 
    if(n!=freq.length)
        return;

    Map<Character,Integer> unsorted=new HashMap<>();
    //this will merge your both array into single map with key as char and freq as value
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        unsorted.put(ele[i],freq[i]);
    }
    
    Map<Character, Integer> sorted = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    unsorted.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<Character, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .forEachOrdered(x -> sorted.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
    sorted.forEach((k,v)->
    {

        System.out.println(k+" --> "+v);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for both way of sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char ele[] = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    int freq[] = new int[]{5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    Map<Character, Integer> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
         inputMap.put(ele[i],freq[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(inputMap);

    // sort in desc
    Map<Character, Integer> sortedDesc = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    inputMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<Character, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedDesc.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

    System.out.println(sortedDesc);
    System.out.println(sortedDesc.keySet());

    // sort in asc
    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> sortedAsc = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    inputMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedAsc.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
    System.out.println(sortedAsc);
    System.out.println(sortedAsc.keySet());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to be more specific. Are you wanting to sort the char array based on the int array's corresponding ordered integer when converted from char? For example, [ 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e' ] and [ 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 ] becomes [ 'c', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'd' ]? Or should the integers in the int array represent indexes for the char array? For example, given the same arrays for the last instance, we would now have an output of [ 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'c' ]. The question needs more context.

I've made two simple and elegant solutions to solve both cases, anyway. They are simple in the fact that they avoid any complex data structures like HashMaps or TreeMaps and just use arrays. Enjoy :)

**Case 1**

```
char ele[] = new char[] { 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e' };
int freq[] = new int[] { 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 };
Arrays.sort(ele);
char sortedEle[] = new char[ele.length];
int idxCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < ele.length; j++) {
       if (freq[i] == j + 1) {
           sortedEle[idxCounter] = ele[j];
           idxCounter++;
       }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedEle));
```

**Case 2**

```
char ele[] = new char[] { 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e' };
int freq[] = new int[] { 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 };
char sortedEle[] = new char[ele.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    int idx = freq[i] - 1;
    sortedEle[idx] = ele[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedEle));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an efficient "[Bubble Sort](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/bubble-sort)" algorithm to sort both the arrays. The criteria of the sort will only apply to the array of integers, but when repositioning its elements, you could reposition the elements of the array of characters as well.

This approach is straightforward but requires knowledge of the "Bubble Sort". Some of the answers posted by others are more efficient. But this is just a simple way of doing it.

```
        char[] arrayOfChars = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' } ;
        int[] arrayOfInts = { 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 } ;

        int index, limit = 4 ;
        boolean swapped ;        

        do
        {
            swapped = false ;
            index = 0 ;

            while(index < limit)
            {
                if(arrayOfInts[index] > arrayOfInts[index+1])
                {
                    // swapping places of the integer elements
                    int tempInt = arrayOfInts[index] ;
                    arrayOfInts[index] = arrayOfInts[index+1] ;
                    arrayOfInts[index+1] = tempInt ;

                    // swapping places of the adjacent character elements
                    char tempChar = arrayOfChars[index] ;
                    arrayOfChars[index] = arrayOfChars[index+1] ;
                    arrayOfChars[index+1] = tempChar ;

                    swapped = true ;
                }

                index++ ;
            }

            limit-- ;
        }
        while(swapped) ;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfInts)) ;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfChars)) ;
```